# Enable buttons if an action has been taken in JPanel, otherwise turn them off

Tags: java, image, swing

I have JFrame which contains JPanel that enable the user to add images by clicking JButton shows JFileChooser then the user choose any image to show. It works fine, there is no problem here, but i have others JButtons, for example : button that shows the image information(That image inside the JPanel) so i want to disable it until any image has been loaded to the JPanel then it will be enabled, if there is no image the buttons turned off, that's it.. i have so many buttons that related to any image entered to that JPanel, so the user can click on them even though there is no image or painting or whatever !

I want to control the event in the JPanel to avoid clicking buttons or JMenuItems that have tasks related to occur an event in JPanel...

and Thank you so much for your great website, and everyone here..

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Answer (score 0):

1. set them off by default
2. in event, where you load picture into JPanel, manually turn them on using `JButton.setEnabled(true)` on each one of them

I hope this is what are you asking for, seems pretty straight forward to me. Of course the buttons must be visible to the class where you load data to JPanel. Same goes for menu items